# How to replace certain string text in the Gatsby site at build time?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, gatsby

I have a Gatsby v5 site with Sanity as a CMS. All of my pages are static. Some pages are hardcoded through Gatsby /pages and the remaining are generated by data from Sanity at the build time.

I want to have a feature where I can put a placeholder text like `{current_year}` in the hardcoded pages or in Sanity content blocks and it should be replaced with 2024 (using `new Date().getFullYear().toString()`) at build time.

Can we use [onCreateWebpackConfig](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreateWebpackConfig) or [onCreateBabelConfig](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreateBabelConfig) or using any other lifecycle method?

Grateful for any help/suggestions/lead

I have tried adding a custom babel plugin for replacing the text.

gatsby-node

```
exports.onCreateBabelConfig = ({ actions }: { actions: any }) => {
  actions.setBabelPlugin({
    name: "./plugins/my-babel-plugin-replace-placeholder",
  });
};
```

/plugins/my-babel-plugin-replace-placeholder.js

```
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
  console.log("my-babel-plugin-replace-placeholder.js");
  return {
    visitor: {
      StringLiteral(path, state) {
        const node = path.node;

        // Replace {current_year} with the current year at runtime
        if (t.isStringLiteral(node) && node.value.includes("{current_year}")) {
          node.value = node.value.replace(
            /{current_year}/g,
            new Date().getFullYear().toString(),
          );
        }
      },
    },
  };
};
```

I have treid adding a string to /pages/index.tsx - `` {`{current_year}`} ``. However, it did not work.